# Webpack config babel errors, other answers not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am trying to set up React with webpack on my windows machine, but I'm getting a very strange response to a very common error. I've got the "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import" error that everyone seems to ask about on stackoverflow, but I think I've looked at every question and none of the solutions that work for others have worked for me.

I've added babel-preset-es2015 and es2016 to my package.json:

```
{
"name": "360",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "360 video viewer",
"main": "/src/index.js",
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "compile": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack",
  "build": "webpack",
  "start": "webpack-dev-server"
},
"author": "DottoraQN",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
  "jquery": "^3.2.1",
  "react": "^15.5.4",
  "react-dom": "^15.5.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
  "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
  "babel-preset-es2016": "^6.24.1",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
  "webpack": "^2.6.1",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
  }
}
```

I've added both to my .babelrc:

```
{"presets": ["es2015", "es2016", "react"]}
```

And I've made sure to specify babel correctly in my webpack.config.js file:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
    template: __dirname + '/build/index.html',
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: 'body'
});

var config = {
  entry: __dirname + '/src/index.js',
  output: {
     path: __dirname + '/build',
     filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        query: {
           presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
    }]
  },
  plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig]
};

module.exports = config;
```

My code is really simple, I'm just trying to display "hello world" in my localhost server, which actually works! But, the code is still throwing this error and is causing unidentified functions in other places.

I'm really sorry for asking this question again, but like I said, other answers just aren't working for me and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm relatively new to react and es6, I took a codecademy class and wanted to try writing my websites in react, cause I like the modular format. Thank you for your help and your patience!

**EDIT:**

Here is my index.js/React module:

```
//index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Viewer from './Viewer';

//var React = require('react');
//var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
//var Viewer = require('./Viewer');

ReactDOM.render(
  <Viewer />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);

//Viewer.js
import React from 'react';

export default class Viewer extends React.Component {
    parseMe () {
        $.getJSON("images.json", function(images) {
            console.log(images);
        });
    }

    render () {
        return (<div>
            <p>Hello World</p>
            </div>);
    }
}
```

The function parseMe() is not in use currently, as it doesn't actually work with the errors I'm currently getting.

**ANSWER:**

Well, there wasn't really one. In the comments on this question, you can see that another user took my project and cloned it, and it worked fine for them. I ended up just reinstalling my node modules and everything started working.

Comment: Can you post what's in index.js or how are you writing react code,  because I just copied your config and ran basic react hello world app with it. It works perfectly fine. (I am using node 6)

Comment: @roxxypoxxy Posted :)

Comment: Interesting, it is working on my end.

Comment: Here's what works for me https://github.com/RohitRox/hello-react-from-webpack if it helps, which is exactly what you have.

Comment: Well, I have no idea how our two project directories are different, but I downloaded yours from github and it works, while mine still doesn't. Thank you for the help, even though it seems like there's just something arbitrarily wrong with my file structure :)

Comment: If everything's' same and it works then I would say try re-installing npm modules in your project. `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`

Comment: I went ahead and did that and it's working great! Thanks for your help, and I'll update my question with the answer

Comment: I am glad that it worked. No prob.